# Why does NSPredicate with block fail when evaluating nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I discovered this when debugging a crash with `NSPredicate`. It seems like it does not check for nil values properly.

```
let blockPredicate = NSPredicate(block: { (object, _) -> Bool in
    guard let object = object as? String else {
        return false
    }
    return true
})

blockPredicate.evaluateWithObject("Hello")  // true
blockPredicate.evaluateWithObject(nil)      // EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)
```

The documentation states this should work.

```
public init(block: (AnyObject, [String : AnyObject]?) -> Bool)
public func evaluateWithObject(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool // evaluate a predicate against a single object
```

The block should receive a proper `AnyObject` but instead a `nil` pointer `0x0` is passed in. It's not possible to check for `nil` with `if let object = object` or `object != nil` because the compiler will not accept it.

Is this a bug or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: In Swift 3, it is now `init(block: @escaping (Any?, [String : Any]?) -> Bool)` so this problem should not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the block type says it should be a non optional `AnyObject`. In reality it can be `nil`, so it should be `AnyObject?`.

A solution is to wrap it in an `Optional` and then unwrap it again.

```
let blockPredicate = NSPredicate(block: { (object, _) -> Bool in
    let optionalObject = Optional(object)
    guard let object = optionalObject as? String else {
        return false
    }
    return true
})
```

Comment: Nice , it didn't occur to me to cast the inbound as Optional

Comment: Actually this fails for me with optimized `-Os` builds. I'm guessing the optimizer removes the wrapping and unwrapping.

Comment: The type has changed. It's now `init(block: (Any?, [String : Any]?) -> Bool)`, so everything works just fine now.